# Subspaces of the set of real valued functions over an interval.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Show that the integral of all continuous real-valued functions on the interval [0,1] equal to b $\in$ R is a subspace of $R^{[0, 1]}$ if and only if b=0.

So I am assuming that because both the integral and $R^{[0, 1]}$ are over the same interval, that is significant somehow? 
Also I can say the zero function is contained in this set. 
I'm not sure how to show this is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, and I don't know why b=0 for the integral to be a subspace of $R^{[0, 1]}$.

Can someone help explain this question to me?

Comment: I think the statement of the problem is meant to be, the set of all continuous real-valued functions with $$\int_0^1f(x)\,dx=b$$ is a subspace, etc., etc.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose this was a vector space. Take $f$ and $g$ to be continuous functions on $[0,1]$ for which $\int f dx = b$ and $\int g dx = b$. If this were a vector space then we would have $\int (f+g) dx = b$ as well. However, we know that $\int (f+g) dx = 2b$, thus $2b = b$ and $b=0$.

This demonstrates that the set can only be a vector space if $b$ was zero. Now show that given $b$ is zero, this set constitutes a subspace. That is show that the collection of all continuous functions with zero integral is a subspace.